# Pandas select only the first 3 YYYYMM per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

CGood afternoon,

I have a datrame like the one below

```
+---+---+--------+
|   |USR| MMMMYY |
+---+---+--------+
| 1 | A | 200002 |
+---+---+--------+
| 2 | A | 200003 |
+---+---+--------+
| 3 | A | 200004 |
+---+---+--------+
| 4 | A | 200005 |
+---+---+--------+
| 5 | B | 200001 |
+---+---+--------+
| 6 | B | 200003 |
+---+---+--------+
| 7 | B | 200008 |
+---+---+--------+
| 8 | B | 200009 |
+---+---+--------+
```

I need to get only the first three *CONSECUTIVE MMMMYY per USR.

```
+---+---+--------+
|   |USR| MMMMYY |
+---+---+--------+
| 1 | A | 200002 |
+---+---+--------+
| 2 | A | 200003 |
+---+---+--------+
| 3 | A | 200004 |
+---+---+--------+
| 5 | B | 200001 |
+---+---+--------+
| 6 | B | 200003 |
+---+---+--------+
```

Im able to get the first 3 records using head(3)

```
df.sort_values(['USR', 'MMMMYY' ], ascending=[True, True]).groupby('USR', as_index=False).head(3)
```

but of course it dont bring back what I need, neither using

```
df['mm_dif']=df.groupby(['USR'])['MMMMYY'].diff()

df['mm_dif2']=df.groupby(['USR'])['MMMMYY'].diff(-1)

df['check']=np.where((df.mm_dif==1) | (df.mm_dif2==-1),True,False)
```

it gets the consecutive when ['check'] is true but in some cases I may need to get 200001 and 200003 only and they are not consecutive between them. Any guidance will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I don't get why `B 200008` is not chosen. Also `MMMMYY` doesn't look like a valid date format.

Comment: Is not selected because for B it would be the first three months starting in 200001.
The MMMMYY Im converting to datetime with the first date of the month, or I will get issues when the first value for a USR is 200011 or 200012
* Added Consecutive in the question for clarity. my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MMMMYY` is datetime, then turn it to `datetime` type first:

```
df['MMMMYY'] = pd.to_datetime(df.MMMMYY, format='%Y%m')

s = df.groupby('USR')['MMMMYY'].transform('min') + pd.offsets.MonthOffset(3)

df[df.MMMMYY<s]
```

Output:

```
  USR     MMMMYY
1   A 2000-02-01
2   A 2000-03-01
3   A 2000-04-01
5   B 2000-01-01
6   B 2000-03-01
```

Comment: It is a datetime in this case

Comment: @gizq what do you get when you do `print(df.MMMMYY.dtype)`?

Comment: I get an int64, but I have to convert to datetime, or for series starting like usr F MMMYY 200011 I will have issues with the 200101

Comment: Thank you  monthOffset and the comparison worked perfect Thank you!